# PHP print newline into textarea

Tags: php, javascript, html, textarea, newline

I'm trying to print newline into textarea.

I have this string:

`$coords = $row->lat.','.$row->lon."\r\n"`

When I use the following javascript command:

```
alert(coords);
```

I get:

```
-35.308401,149.124298
-35.307841,149.124298
```

However, when I view it in a textarea, I get:

```
-35.308401,149.124298 -35.307841,149.124298
```

How do I make the newlines display in the textarea?

**More Information:**

alert window display:

[image: alert window]

textarea:
[image]

Code:

```
<textarea name="addrs" rows=5 cols=80>-35.308401,149.124298 -35.307841,149.124298</textarea>
```

**Further Information:**
This is how form is created and text written to textarea

```
function openMapWindow (data) {
    alert(data);

    var mapForm = document.createElement("form");
    mapForm.target = "Map";
    mapForm.method = "POST"; // or "post" if appropriate
    mapForm.action = "http://www.xxx.com/map.php";

    var mapInput = document.createElement("input");
    mapInput.type = "text";
    mapInput.name = "addrs";
    mapInput.value = data;
    mapForm.appendChild(mapInput);

    document.body.appendChild(mapForm);

    map = window.open("", "Map", "status=0,title=0,height=600,width=800,scrollbars=1");

    if (map) {
        mapForm.submit();
    } else {
        alert('You must allow popups for this map to work.');
    }

}

function mapSuppliers(customer_id) {
    $.get("get.map.points.php", { c_id: customer_id },
     function(data){
         if (data!='') {
            openMapWindow(data);
         } else {
             alert("Missing map coordinates - cannot display map (data: " + data + ")");
         }
     });

}
```

Comment: When you view the source of the page with your web browser, is there a line return as you expect?

Comment: You say PHP, but you test via JS. How are you actually passing the data to the textarea? Is it inline via PHP ?

Comment: How did your edit answer my question? If anything it raises the question how is `openMapWindow()` relevant.

Comment: @Khez: Line12 of edited code: `mapInput.value = data;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is quite old already, but I will post my answer just in case anyone comes here.

For example, if we would like to show this text in textarea:

```
hi Masume
have a nice day!
```

With PHP:

```php
echo "hi Masume".chr(13)."have a nice day!";
```

With JS:

```js
textareaElement = 'hi Masume' + String.fromCharCode(13) + 'have a nice day!';
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to have multiple rows in an input field.

Consider updating your code to:

```
var mapTextarea = document.createElement("textarea");
mapTextarea.name = "addrs";
mapTextarea.value = data;
mapForm.appendChild(mapTextarea);
```

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 the only thing that puzzles me now. Is the screenshot with what appears to be a textarea, it might be css though.

Comment: I still can't connect that PHP line and JS code. Maybe I'm missing something, or I'm too tired and my brain doesn't work well at the moment.

Comment: Yes - I tried to answer that myself but the system wont let me... I couldn't find a createElement() type = textarea - The MS reference only said text so I used it... I submit the form to a page which catches the data, maps it and re-displays it in a textarea.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5 - see new code edited - it uses a get call to another page which returns the data in a simple text format and all that is written back to calling ajax is `$coords = $row->lat.','.$row->lon."\r\n"` once the loop completes I simply `print $coords;` inside get.map.points.php

Comment: oops!!! Just re-read it - implemented incorrectly!!! You are the man Khez . Problem Fixed!